# Practical example of a survey statistical research

Tags: survey

A juice distributor delivering boxes of 8 bottles knows the probability (p=0.02) that a bottle will break during transport. If 4000 trunks are transported, the number of trunks in which two or more broken bottles will be found is approximately:
a. 85
b.14
c. 3960
d. 41
e. 40

Could you find the correct answer. I know it's 41, but I can't realize how they got to it...

Thank you in advance if you try solving this!